# Existe no framework .Net, alguma classe de leitura atrasada?

Tags: c#, .net, lazy-loading

Gostaria de saber se no .Net existe alguma classe que me permita dizer para ela como ler um dado, mas que **NÃO faça a leitura imediatamente**... só mais tarde quando for requisitada, essa classe faz a leitura e armazena o valor, para caso sejam feitas várias leituras.

Algo do tipo:

```
var delayedDb = DelayedReader.Create(() => LerAlgoDoBancoDeDados());

var resultado = dadoDaMemoria != null ? dadoDaMemoria :
                delayedDb.Read() != null ? delayedDb.Read() :
                null;
```

Para evitar que eu tenha que fazer isso:

```
var dadoDoBanco = LerAlgoDoBancoDeDados();

var resultado = dadoDaMemoria != null ? dadoDaMemoria :
                dadoDoBanco != null ? dadoDoBanco :
                null;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Então, não conheço muito bem essa funcionalidade do .NET, mas fazendo uma procura você acha o `Lazy<T>` que faz o mesmo trabalho que o `Lazy Loading` do `Entity Framework`, mas com esse você consegue fazer o `Lazy Loading` nas suas classes.

Um [artigo](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/620215/Four-Ways-to-Implement-Lazy-Loading-in-Csharp) com um exemplo deste.

Bom, um exemplo de como utilizar esta classe:

```
public class Proprietario
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public Lazy<IEnumerable<Propriedade>> Propriedades = null;

    public Proprietario()
    {
        this.Propriedades = new Lazy<IEnumerable<Propridade>>();
    }
}
```

Neste momento, a classe proprietário está criada e com todas as suas propriedades devidamente cadastradas, em seu construtor, o `Lazy Loading` foi instânciado e já está pronto para uso.
Para utiliza-lo, você instância a classe `Proprietário` e, por fim, você faz `IEnumerable<Propriedade> propriedades = Poprietario.Propriedades.Value`.

Comment: Ótimo artigo que você indicou. Você poderia trazer mais informações para a sua resposta de forma que ela fique mais detalhada? Por exemplo como usar a classe `Lazy`. Valeu! =)

Comment: @beta, importante você incluir que esta classe só está disponível a partir da versão 4 do framework.

Comment: Então, estava corrido aqui na empresa, respondi o básico mesmo, mas vou editar a resposta com maiores informações.

Comment: Por esse exemplo em particular, era preciso clarificar que `Propriedades.Value` ha de criar um `IEnumerable<Propriedade>` vazio...quer dizer, sem mais nada, o _default construtor_ do `T` em `Lazy<T>`  é invocado. Se o _default construtor_ tem em si o trabalho caro, entao, tudo bem. Mas normalmente se vê `Lazy<T>` usado com o delegado que faz o trabalho caro. Usando o exemplo original: `Lazy<Collection<Dados>> DelayedReader = new Lazy<Collection<Dados>>(() => LerAlgoDoBancoDeDados());` e entao, o ler (trabalho caro) so acontessa na invocacao de `DelayedReader.Value`

Answer (score 2):

Como foi dito que a classe `Lazy<T>` está disponível nas versões **somente a partir do .Net 4**, aqui vai uma implementação para quem precisar de algo parecido, que é a que eu estava usando anteriormente, e que funciona com o .Net 2.0 ou superior.

Isso não é um clone da classe Lazy, é uma implementação minha. O mecanismo da classe é **thread-safe**, com penalidade somente na primeira leitura usando o método `Read`, ou quando o método `ReadRefresh` for usado. Após o primeiro uso, não é possível descartar o valor interno do cache, por causa de ser thread-safe... por isso não existe um método `ClearCache`. Para se livrar do cache a variável deve ser recolhidade pelo coletor de lixo (garbage-collector).

```
public static class Delayed
{
    public static Delayed<T> Create<T>(Delayed<T>.Getter getter)
    {
        return new Delayed<T>(getter);
    }
}

public class Delayed<T>
{
    public delegate T Getter();

    private bool hasValue;
    private T value;
    private Getter getter;

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="getter"></param>
    public Delayed(Getter getter)
    {
        if (getter == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("getter");
        this.getter = getter;
        this.value = default(T);
        this.hasValue = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads the value of the Delayed object, using the value from the cache if available, storing the value in a permanent cache.
    /// </summary>
    public T Read()
    {
        if (!this.hasValue)
        {
            lock (this.getter)
            {
                if (!this.hasValue)
                {
                    this.hasValue = true;
                    this.value = this.getter();
                }
            }
        }

        return this.value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads the value of the Delayed object, refreshing the value in a permanent cache.
    /// </summary>
    public T ReadFresh()
    {
        lock (this.getter)
        {
            this.hasValue = true;
            this.value = this.getter();
        }

        return this.value;
    }
}
```